# Resonance Frequency of system with two inductors

Tags: inductor, frequency, passive-networks, resonance

I am trying to derive a formula for the resonance frequency of the following circuit:
[image: A RLC circuit with two inductors]
The piece that is giving me trouble are the two inductors, that (although I might be wrong) cannot be further simplified. Therefore, it is not possible to use the known/basic formulas for RLC circuits which either are completely in parallel, or in series (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit).

I hope that one of you will be able to get me going by providing some hints, or pointing me to a source where I can look up the answer. In any case, thank you for your trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impedance of the parallel RLC is known, and it is obtained by putting together the three admittances and then reciprocating:

z1 = 1/(1/R + jwC + 1/jwL2)

The you add the inductor L1 in series

z2 = z1 + jwL1

This is the total impedance.
Then the resonance frequencies correspond to the poles of the circuit (Note: if the poles are real, ok , no resonance; if they are complex, you consider the imaginary part). Now, it's easier to take the zeros of the admittance: y2 = 1/z2

These zeros are the indication of the resonance frequencies of the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine 2L’s as 2R’s and compute Thevenin equivalent L then use the equivalent L.

This will give the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ztot = ZL1 + (ZL2 // ZC // ZR)

ZL1 = jwL1

ZL2 = jwL2

ZC = 1 / jwC

ZR = R

Afterwards, set to zero the denominator of Ztot to zero.

You will have to solve a third order polynomial equation in w.

w is omega.

Answer (score -1):

> *The piece that is giving me trouble are the two inductors, that
> (although I might be wrong) cannot be further simplified.*

Just treat the two inductors as two resistors: -

[image]

So, that's the answer, now can you see why it is like that? Do you know about source transformations and Thevenin's theorem? Can you see how to calculate the resonant frequency now for this modified circuit?